# Background image doesn't show up

Tags: html, css, background-image

I have tried following tutorials on W3schools, and I've also dug into Developer Tools on the website I'm tasked with cloning, and have gone back to my previous project when I had to do a `background image`.

I know this is a user error, but I am stuck.

My HTML looks like this:

```
<section class="introduction">  <img src="background-image">
```

and my CSS looks like this:

```
.introduction {
  background-image: url('../images/karma-background.jpg'); 
}
```

Comment: It seems you forgot to include a question in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't require an image object

```
<img src="...">
```

css and background images work like so.

```
<section class="introduction"></section>

.introduction {
background-image:url('../images/karma-background.jpg'); 
}
```

so actually the problem is you haven't ended your section tag like I have in my example. You may have to add additional css for sizing

Answer (score 2):

you need to set `height` and `width` for `background-image` to work

```css
.introduction {
  background-image: url('//dummyimage.com/200x200'); 
  height:200px;
  width:200px;
}
```

```html
<section class="introduction">This text has a background image</section>
```

Or you can simply use img `src` as you had in your code, but won't be a `background`

```css
img {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<section class="introduction">
  <img src="//dummyimage.com/200x200" />
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a couple of learning opportunities here for a new coder.

First, let's look at your `<img>` tag.  The `src` attribute of the image tag is used to refer to an actual image file.  To use it, you might say:

```
<img src="../images/karma.jpg" />
```

an equivalent, but less common expression would be:

```
<img src="../images/karma.jpg"></image>
```

In your sample, you have the attribute `src="background-image"`, which suggests that you are trying to use as though it were the `class` or `style` attribute.  In some situations, this might be a step on the right track, but not here.

The `<img>` tag is really intended for content images in the *foreground*.  Because you are specifically trying to use an image for the *background*, your CSS is the best place for the reference to the background image.  Therefore, the `<img>` tag you have is unnecessary, and perhaps contributing to your confusion.

Here's one variation that would make your code work:

```
<section class="introduction">
     Lorum ipsum dolor sit amet
</section>

.introduction {
    background-image: url('../images/karma-background.jpg');
}
```

By including any kind of content at all between your opening and closing `<section>` tags, the browser knows how much space needs to be filled with a background, and will use some or all of the file `karma-background.jpg` to fill it.  Alternately, you can hard-code the size you want filled with a background image:

```
.introduction {
    background-image: url('../images/karma-background.jpg');
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
}
```

Comment: I really appreciate you taking the time to respond....I was really intimidated to post, and it looks as though I didn't post properly...so, again, thank you for looking past that and giving me this feedback.